# Multiple docker hosts

Tags: traefik

Is it possible to link traefik to two docker hosts directly?

I can add one docker host to the traefik.toml via tcp or a unix socket. But there doesn't appear to be a way to add two.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this would be not to run two Docker containers separately. You can run your containers in **[Docker SWARM mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/#feature-highlights)** as a cluster, with a replication factor of two (Since you mentioned two explicitly, the value is based on your SWARM cluster nodes). Then you can provide the SWARM cluster manager node IP into your traefik.toml config. Docker SWARM will take care of the load balancing among the replicated containers.